# Combining results from two calls to Select-Object

Tags: powershell

As part of a PowerShell script, I want to generate a list of subfolders of two different folders. I approached this by calling `Get-ChildItem` twice, using `Select-Object` to transform the paths, and trying to combine the results. However, this is the combining step where I got stuck. I have tried this:

```
$cur = Get-Location
$mainDirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name | Select-Object {"$cur\$_"}
$appDirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name Applications\Programs |
           Select-Object {"$cur\Applications\Programs\$_"}
$dirs = $mainDirs,$appDirs      #Doesn't work!
```

But `$dirs` ends up consisting of the entries from `$mainDirs` followed by as many null items as many items there are in `$appDirs`.

How can I combine these in PowerShell?

**Edit:** The output of `mainDirs[0]`:

```
"$cur\$_"                
---------                
D:\somefolder\somesubfolder
```

The output of `appDirs[0]`:

```
"$cur\Applications\Programs\$_"                        
-------------------------------                        
D:\somefolder\Applications\Programs\othersubfolder
```

Comment: Use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to parse subfolders

Comment: @Manu I don't need all of them

Comment: what is the output of `$mainDirs[0]` and `$appDirs[0]`?

Comment: Recurse all and filter out the result with `Select-String` (alias `sls`).  e.g. `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Name Applications\Programs | sls -pattern "Applications\Programs" -casesensitive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` accepts a string array as input. Simply pass both folders whose subfolders you want listed as an array. Expand the `FullName` property to get the paths of subfolders:

```
$folders = '.', '.\Applications\Programs'
$dirs    = Get-ChildItem $folders -Directory | Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

If you want the relative rather than the absolute path remove the current directory from the beginning of the path strings:

```
$pattern = '^{0}\\' -f [regex]::Escape($PWD.Path)
$folders = '.', '.\Applications\Programs'
$dirs    = Get-ChildItem $folders -Directory |
           ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace $pattern }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely what I wanted to achieve